# How to Group By many keys in Spark RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, group-by, rdd

Imagine I have a triplet :

```
val RecordRDD : RDD[Int, String, Int] = {

                (5 , "x1", 100),
                (3 , "x2", 200),
                (3 , "x4", 300),
                (5 , "x1", 150),
                (3 , "x2", 160),
                (5 , "x1", 400)
  }
```

How can I efficiently group them by the first two elements and sort by the third? For example make it:

```
                [5 , [  "x1" -> [100, 150, 400]  ]
                [3 , [   ["x2" -> [160, 200]],   ["x4" -> [300]]    ]
```

I am looking for an efficient way.

Should I make it a DataFrame and make use of GroupBy(Col1,Col2) and SortBy(Col3)?

Would that be more efficient than groupBy of Spark RDD?

Can AggregateByKey aggregate on 2 keys simultaneously?

*You can suppose this RDD is pretty large! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You didn't mention which version of Spark you are running, but one way of doing this with RDDs is like this:

```
val result = RecordRDD
  .map{case(x, y, z) => ((x,y), List(z))}
  .reduceByKey(_++_)
  .map{case(key, list) => (key._1, Map((key._2 -> list.sorted)))}
  .reduceByKey(_++_)
```

I don't know if it is *the* most efficient way, but it is pretty efficient ;)

Comment: If my answer was helpful, could you then please accept the answer?

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt Why `.map{case(x, y, z) => ((x,y), List(z))}.reduceByKey(_++_)` and not `.map{case(x, y, z) => ((x,y), List(z))}.groupByKey`? This is very inefficient.

Comment: Well, in this case you could use either, but I have made it a habit to always use `reduceByKey` rather than `groupByKey` as `groupByKey` is frequently  inefficient compared to `reduceByKey` (see why [here](https://blog.knoldus.com/2015/06/19/shufflling-and-repartitioning-of-rdds-in-apache-spark/) ).

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt I have accepted your answer, but because of my reputation (less than 15) it is not appeared. Thanks once again. Also I dont know why my reputation remains 1... :(

Comment: can someone explain what the reduceByKey is doing here? I can't understand from running the example piece by piece.

Comment: @alex it appends all the values (which in this case are lists) for the different keys. `++` is scala shorthand for appending lists.